# Filling a DataGridView with a List<List<String>>()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This question may be hard to explain. I'm writing a C# VS 2012 WinForms application that involves me getting data from one list and putting that into a list with columns. I have a,

```
public List<List<string>> allRows = new List<List<string>>();
```

to allow for the list without columns to be put into columns, here is the code that does that,

```
//LOOP THAT PUTS LIST INTO COLUMNS
for (int i = 0; i < fullData.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % 6 == 0)
        allRows.Add(new List<string>());
    allRows.Last().Add(fullData[i]);
}

// final result giving me answers in columns
string path = String.Format("C:\\Users\\sackermann\\Desktop\\result.txt"); 
File.WriteAllLines(path, allRows.Select(row => string.Join(" ", row)));
```

I was wondering if there was anyway I could possible put each of the columns of the `List<List<String>>` into a `DataGridView`?

Comment: I guess you have to use some kind of adapter to turn `List<List<string>>` into something which `DataGridView` can hold. The most suitable one is `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a class with the properties defined in it, and then have a `List<customClass>` then it would be simple. Plus it defines the column names for you. Not sure if that is feasible in your situation.

```
public class foo
{
 public string foo1 {get;set;}
 public string foo2 {get;set;}
}

public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 var foo = new foo() ;
 foo.foo1 = "some";
 foo.foo2 = "text";
 List<foo> _foo = new List<foo>();
 _foo.Add(foo);
 dgv.DataSource = _foo;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example? If not, that's alright.